# django cookie not deleting after it is expired

Tags: django, cookies

I set a cookie with max_age of 30 seconds like:

```
response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({}), content_type='application/json')
location = {'state':state_name,
            'city':city_name,
            'locality':locality_name}

response.set_cookie('location',location, max_age=30 )
return response
```

however i can still see the cookie in browser console after the expiry time.

Question is If i set a cookie using django set_cookie method, will it be deleted automatically after it is expired? If not how can i do it so that it gets deleted immediately after expiry.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie will not be `deleted` automatically.

While the cookie still `exists` and may be visible in your console/browser, once the cookie is expired, your browser and Django will ignore it as it does even exist.

You can test it:

```
if request.COOKIES.get('mycookie', None) is None:
    # if cookie is expired do this
else:
    # if cookie still exists do something else
```